# XML parser - how to get values from Nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have question about parsing an XML File. Lets say I have XML file:

```
<line>
   <point>
      <X>100</X>
      <Y>100</Y>
   </point>
   <point>
      <X>200</X>
      <Y>200</Y>
   </point>
</line>
```

and I would like to parse it using `DOM`:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("point");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("x: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0).getTextContent());
```

---

But - how can i  get X and Y from XML file as integers? -  first X as x1, first Y as y1 and second X as x2 and second Y as y2 ?

I tried:

```
int x1 = Integer.valueOf(eElement.getAttribute("X"));
int y1 = Integer.valueOf(eElement.getAttribute("Y"));
```

but without success

Comment: does your `System.out.println()` work as expected?

Comment: Every line have two `point`s and follow that structure?

Comment: System.out.println works without problem

Comment: yes, every line has two point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Get the <line> element
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("line");
Element line = (Element) nList.item(0);

// Get each <point> element from the <line>
Element point1 = (Element) line.getElementsByTagName("point").item(0);
Element point2 = (Element) line.getElementsByTagName("point").item(1);

// Get each <X> and <Y> from each <point> retrieved before
Integer x1 = Integer.parseInt(point1.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0).getTextContent());
Integer y1 = Integer.parseInt(point1.getElementsByTagName("Y").item(0).getTextContent());
Integer x2 = Integer.parseInt(point2.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0).getTextContent());
Integer y2 = Integer.parseInt(point2.getElementsByTagName("Y").item(0).getTextContent());
```

The whole code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("line");

Element line = (Element) nList.item(0);

Element point1 = (Element) line.getElementsByTagName("point").item(0);
Element point2 = (Element) line.getElementsByTagName("point").item(1);

Integer x1 = Integer.parseInt(point1.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0).getTextContent());
Integer y1 = Integer.parseInt(point1.getElementsByTagName("Y").item(0).getTextContent());
Integer x2 = Integer.parseInt(point2.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0).getTextContent());
Integer y2 = Integer.parseInt(point2.getElementsByTagName("Y").item(0).getTextContent());

System.out.println("x1: " + x1 + "\ty1: " + y1 + "\tx2: " + x2 + "\ty2: " + y2);
```

Output:

```
x1: 100 y1: 100 x2: 200 y2: 200
```